# Session timeout random issue

Tags: java, session

I have issue came from multiple clients.

In our web application which is based on Spring, hibernate there is only default session time out 30 minutes.

However with some users randomly session time out in one or two minutes only, I have verify code in very detailed level that we have not session invalidate specify anywhere and there is not case which is occurred in any specific code, so that there is no meaning to put any code here.

So I think there may be server level issue, so I just only want to know that, have anybody else has face same issues ever? and if yes what could be problems?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which server do you use?